# What is the requirement for a uniform continuous function to be Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If a function is uniformly continuous, what else is needed for it to be Lipschitz?

Is there any existing conclusion about the functional that maps Lipschitz function to Lipschitz function?

Thanks.